# Compiling PHP, are these errors ok? (Linux-Debian-PHP5.3.3)

Tags: php, linux, compilation, debian, php-5.3

Are these ok? My config line is this:

```
./configure  --enable-fastcgi --enable-fpm --with-mcrypt --with-zlib --enable-mbstring --with-openssl --with-mysql --with-mysql-sock --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib --enable-gd-native-ttf --without-sqlite --disable-pdo --disable-reflection --with-curl --with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config
```

And these are the results:

```
=====================================================================
TEST RESULT SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Exts skipped    :   47
Exts tested     :   32
---------------------------------------------------------------------

Number of tests : 11216              8105
Tests skipped   : 3111 ( 27.7%) --------
Tests warned    :    0 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
Tests failed    :   38 (  0.3%) (  0.5%)
Expected fail   :    8 (  0.1%) (  0.1%)
Tests passed    : 8059 ( 71.9%) ( 99.4%)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Time taken      :  711 seconds
=====================================================================

=====================================================================
FAILED TEST SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Class constant whose initial value refereces a non-existent class [tests/classes/constants_error_004.phpt]
Curl_multi_getcontent() basic test with different sources (local file/http) [ext/curl/tests/curl_multi_getcontent_basic3.phpt]
curl_setopt() basic parameter test [ext/curl/tests/curl_setopt_error.phpt]
timezone_abbreviations_list() tests [ext/date/tests/010.phpt]
Test DateTime::modify() function : usage variation - Passing unexpected values to first argument $modify. [ext/date/tests/DateTime_modify_variation1.phpt]
Bug #48187 (DateTime::diff() corrupting microtime() result) [ext/date/tests/bug48187.phpt]
Bug #50475 (DateTime::setISODate followed by DateTime::setTime) [ext/date/tests/bug50475.phpt]
Bug #51819 (Case discrepancy in timezone names cause Uncaught exception and fatal error) [ext/date/tests/bug51819.phpt]
Bug #51994 (date_parse_from_format is parsing invalid date using 'yz' format) [ext/date/tests/bug51994.phpt]
Bug #52290 (setDate, setISODate, setTime works wrong when DateTime created from timestamp) [ext/date/tests/bug52290.phpt]
Test date_modify() function : usage variation - Passing unexpected values to second argument $format. [ext/date/tests/date_modify_variation2.phpt]
Test timezone_abbreviations_list() function : basic functionality [ext/date/tests/timezone_abbreviations_list_basic1.phpt]
Test 5: HTML Test [ext/dom/tests/dom005.phpt]
mysql connect [ext/mysql/tests/001.phpt]
mysql_connect() [ext/mysql/tests/mysql_connect.phpt]
mysql_[p]connect() - max_links/max_persistent [ext/mysql/tests/mysql_max_links.phpt]
mysqli_connect() [ext/mysqli/tests/mysqli_connect.phpt]
new mysqli() [ext/mysqli/tests/mysqli_connect_oo.phpt]
new mysqli() [ext/mysqli/tests/mysqli_connect_oo_defaults.phpt]
Test for bug 52013 about Phar::decompressFiles(). [ext/phar/tests/bug52013.phpt]
Phar and RecursiveDirectoryIterator [ext/phar/tests/phar_oo_005.phpt]
ReflectionClass::getConstructor() [ext/reflection/tests/ReflectionClass_getConstructor_basic.phpt]
ReflectionMethod::isConstructor() [ext/reflection/tests/ReflectionMethod_constructor_basic.phpt]
ReflectionObject::getConstructor() - basic function test [ext/reflection/tests/ReflectionObject_getConstructor_basic.phpt]
a script should not be able to modify session.use_trans_sid [ext/session/tests/014.phpt]
use_trans_sid should not affect SID [ext/session/tests/015.phpt]
rewriter correctly handles attribute names which contain dashes [ext/session/tests/018.phpt]
rewriter uses arg_seperator.output for modifying URLs [ext/session/tests/020.phpt]
rewriter handles form and fieldset tags correctly [ext/session/tests/021.phpt]
Bug #31454 (Incorrect adding PHPSESSID to links, which contains \r\n) [ext/session/tests/bug36459.phpt]
Bug #41600 (url rewriter tags doesn't work with namespaced tags) [ext/session/tests/bug41600.phpt]
Test session_encode() function : error functionality [ext/session/tests/session_encode_error2.phpt]
SimpleXML: XPath [ext/simplexml/tests/008.phpt]
SPL: DirectoryIterator test getGroup [ext/spl/tests/DirectoryIterator_getGroup_basic.phpt]
SPL: Spl Directory Iterator test getOwner [ext/spl/tests/DirectoryIterator_getOwner_basic.phpt]
SQLite3::open error test [ext/sqlite3/tests/sqlite3_15_open_error.phpt]
Bug #44394 (Last two bytes missing from output) with session.use_trans_id [ext/standard/tests/general_functions/bug44394_2.phpt]
htmlentities() / html_entity_decode() #8592 - #9002 table test [ext/standard/tests/strings/htmlentities17.phpt]
=====================================================================

=====================================================================
EXPECTED FAILED TEST SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
output buffering - fatalism [tests/output/ob_011.phpt]
Inconsistencies when accessing protected members [Zend/tests/access_modifiers_008.phpt]
Inconsistencies when accessing protected members - 2 [Zend/tests/access_modifiers_009.phpt]
Bug #48770 (call_user_func_array() fails to call parent from inheriting class) [Zend/tests/bug48770.phpt]
Bug #48770 (call_user_func_array() fails to call parent from inheriting class) [Zend/tests/bug48770_2.phpt]
Bug #48770 (call_user_func_array() fails to call parent from inheriting class) [Zend/tests/bug48770_3.phpt]
SimpleXML: array casting bug [ext/simplexml/tests/034.phpt]
Bug #39863 (file_exists() silently truncates after a null byte) [ext/standard/tests/file/bug39863.phpt]
=====================================================================
```

Comment: I don't think errors are, you know, *OK*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those test failures are likely to cause serious trouble with your php, if it works at all. For starters, it may have serious trouble talking to MySQL, and issues related to Dates and Times.

Failed tests are almost always a serious problem. Warnings can often be ignored, but ignore unexpected failures at your peril.

Comment: But what do they mean? How can I fix them? There's basically NO documentation on these problems at all that I could find through google, and this is my first time trying to compile php from source. I'm doing an NginX+PHP+FPM+MySQL (LEMP) setup on an unmanaged vps piecing together outdated guides because there are no updated ones for php 5.3.3 on debian >_<

Comment: They're probably due to various dependencies necessary for the compile being missing from your system. I'm not sure what they are since I haven't compiled PHP lately, but I also expect there's a list somewhere.

Comment: I honestly can't find anything at all -_- trying to follow this guide: http://codeshepherd.blogspot.com/2009/05/nginx-phpfpm-memcache-mysql-xcache.html